# Download yum packages on Debian for an offline fedora20 system

Tags: linux, debian, fedora, yum, gstreamer

I need to download YUM packages (namely java-1.7.0-openjdk, gstreamer-plugins-good, gstreamer-plugins-bad and gstreamer-plugins-ugly) for an offline Fedora 20 machine, and I'm working on a Debian 7.

I cannot find directly the package online, only on repositories, repositories i cannot reach.

Any insight?

Comment: Have you searched for the packages on [Koji](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packages)?  For example, you will probably find the correct java-1.7.0-openjdk RPM for your platform [here](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=518269).

Comment: sorry for the late answer, i've tried and i failed, the problem was the lack of the dependencies packages. in the end, i managed to connect the system to the net, and i resolved that way. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

For the record: This can be done using:

```
apt-get install yum-utils
```

make sure that /etc/yum.repos.d/ contains .repo files (take it from target rpm machine)

```
yumdownloader --resolve --destdir DIR  java-1.7.0-openjdk
```